# Is it possible to define a reference to theme

Tags: android, gradle

I have more than one product flavors for my app. Every flavor has different parent theme but all of them have same properties under that theme. So I had to create theme definition under all flavors' dir, and repeat the same properties. Are there any better ways to do this?

Let me be more clear:

I have an app style for flavor1:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  // here are my common style properties
</style>
```

And another app style for my flavor2:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dark.NoActionBar">
  // here are my common style properties
</style>
```

I don't want to repeat common style properties at flavors' resource files dir. So I need something like multiple parent definition, such as:

```
<style name="CommonTheme">
  // here are my common style properties
</style>
```

flavor1:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar,CommonTheme">
</style>
```

flavor2:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dark.NoActionBar,CommonTheme">
</style>
```

This was just a demonstration, I know multiple parents are not allowed.

What I've tried so far?

I thought, defining a reference to a style and using it as a parent may be a solution, such as:

flavor1:

```
<item name="ReferenceTheme" type="style" format="reference">@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar</item>
```

flavor2:

```
<item name="ReferenceTheme" type="style" format="reference">@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dark.NoActionBar</item>
```

main:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/ReferenceTheme">
  // here are my common style properties
</style>
```

But it is not working.

Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: please add a comment while down voting a question.

Comment: no idea why it was down voted, makes perfect sense to me and it a question I'd also like to know the answer to.